# What is the meaning of the word "posting" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, ambiguity

> One form, the OSHA no. 200 serves a dual purpose. it is used as the Log of Occupational Injuries and Illnesses, on which the occurrence and extent of cases are recorded during the year and as the Summary of Occupational Injuries and Illnesses, which is used to summarize the log at the end of the year to satisfy employer **posting** obligations.

This extract is from a book about the OSHA record-keeping forms.

Does "posting" mean "occupational" in this sentence?

Comment: Please give us more information about the source of this quote

Comment: @RonaldSole thank you for your reply. this extract is from a book about the OSHA record-keeping forms and this the complete paragraph as follows: 
One form, the OSHA no. 200 serves a dual purpose. it is used as the Log of Occupational Injuries and Illnesses, on which the occurrence and extent of cases are recorded during the year and as the Summary of Occupational Injuries and Illnesses, which is used to summarize the log at the end of the year to satisfy employer posting obligations.

Comment: You don't say the book, so I have to use guess work and google to find it.  Please don't hide the name of the book!  The book is called "Recordkeeping for Firms selected to participate in the annual survey of of occupational illnesses and injuries".  It is a US federal government guide for firms from 1988.  **Why in the name of God** are you using this to learn English!?

Comment: I don't have this book and I didn't know what its name was.I am majoring in Industrial Engineering and this part of the book ( which I didn't know it's name as I explained) is related to my major. So as an research, I should collect information about this field and translate it and finally present it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employers have a responsibility to *inform* employees of certain facts and rights. They normally do this by putting a poster on the wall in a prominent location.

> A copy of the total and information following the fold line [of OSHA form 200] of the last page of the year must be posted in the place or places where notices to employees are customarily posted. This copy must be posted no later than FEBRUARY 1st...

(quoted from the original source "Recordkeeping for Firms selected to participate in the annual survey of of occupational illnesses and injuries")

Comment: @ James k thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I have another question and i hope I'm not asking too much. Why in this sentence is the word “employer”( which is countable) in this form without any article and s at the end of it? Are these three words "employer posting obligations"  noun?

Comment: Because it is being used as an attributive noun.  Like we say "chicken soup"  (in which "chicken" is a countable noun, but when used to describe a type of soup, it has no article.)

Answer (score 1):

This from Oxford Dictionary:

**post** [transitive] (especially North American English)

to announce something publicly or officially, especially financial information or a warning

*The company posted a $1.1 billion loss.

The aircraft and its crew were posted missing.*